# Exporting state of function from child to parent component

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I am a beginner in React+Redux and have this code for a table. The mapping of the table goes as follows:-

```
ListTemp.js

//editTemp function invoked in the mapping below

 editTemp = (e, temp_id, temp_name, action_url, duration) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.props.getTemp(temp_id)

        this.setState({
            isEdit: true,
            temp_id : temp_id
        });
    }

    changePage(){
        this.setState({
            isEdit : false
        });
    }

    render()

     if(this.state.isEdit === true){
            return(
                <EditTemplate changePage = {this.changePage} isEdit={this.state.isEdit} 
                email = {this.props.email}/>)
        }

        else
        {
        return(
            <table  className = "table_style">
                 <thead>
                     <tr className = "table_style" >
                         <th className = "table_style">TempID</th>
                         <th className = "table_style">Name</th>
                         <th className = "table_style">CreatedOn</th>
                         <th className = "table_style">Action</th>
                     </tr>

               </thead>
               <tbody>
                {
                 this.props.temp_list.map((temp,index)=>
                     <tr className = "table_style">
                         <th className = "table_style">{temp.temp_id}</th>
                         <td className = "table_style">{temp.temp_name}</td>
                         <td className = "table_style">{temp.created_on}</td>
                         <td>
                         <button className="btn btn-info" type = "submit" onClick = {(e) => this.editTemp(e, temp.temp_id, temp.temp_name, temp.action_url, temp.duration)}>
                             EDIT
                         </button> 
                         </td>
                     </tr>
                     )
                 }
                </tbody>
                 </table>
```

Because the table was   having a lot of data, I paginated it and the mapping was moved to a different file along with the editTemp function being called in `onClick` in the code changing it as follows:-

```
ListTemp.js

    showTemp = (temp) => {
        var result = null;
        if (temp.length > 0) {
            result = temp.map((temp, index) => {
                return <ListMapp key={index} temp={temp} index={index} />;
            });
        }
        return result;
    };

    changePage(){
        this.setState({
            isEdit : false
        });
    }

    render()

     if(this.state.isEdit === true){
            return(
                <EditTemplate changePage = {this.changePage} isEdit={this.state.isEdit} 
                email = {this.props.email}/>)
        }

        else
        {
        return(
            <table  className = "table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                        <tr className = "table_style" >
                            <th className = "table_style">TempID</th>
                            <th className = "table_style">Name</th>
                            <th className = "table_style">CreatedOn</th>
                            <th className = "table_style">Action</th>
                        </tr>

                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                           {
                                this.showTemp(rowsPerPage)
                           }
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
```

So the mapping in this.showTemp now comes from:-

```
ListMapp.js

class ListMapp extends Component{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      isEdit : false,
      temp_id : '',
    }
    this.editTemp = this.editTemp.bind(this);
  }



editTemp = (e, temp_id, temp_name, action_url, duration) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.props.getTemp(temp_id)

        this.setState({
            isEdit: true,
            temp_id : temp_id
        });
    }

  render() {
    var { temp, index } = this.props;

      return (
                     <tr className = "table_style">
                         <th className = "table_style">{temp.temp_id}</th>
                         <td className = "table_style">{temp.temp_name}</td>
                         <td className = "table_style">{temp.created_on}</td>
          <td>
             <button className="btn btn-info" type = "submit" onClick = {(e) => this.editTemp(e, temp.temp_id, temp.temp_name, temp.action_url, temp.duration)}>
            EDIT
          </button> 
          </td>               
        </tr>
      );
    }
  }

export default ListMapp;
```

I now need the state of `isEdit` from the `editTemp` function in `ListMapp.js` in `ListTemp.js` to trigger the `if` condition in `render`. How can I do this? In all the related answers I found, the state is sent by linking the onClick to a handleClick function and doing similar in the parent component but I don't see how that can be done here given that onClick in this case is already calling the `isEdit` function which in turn is utitilising mappping from `this.props.temp_list` and has it's own parameters as well. Any help, advice, suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to lift your state up to the parent component from the child component. I'm assuming this is where you are appending the child component `<ListMapp key={index} temp={temp} index={index} />`.

Here, you need to pass an event handling function as a prop to the child.
(for instance) `<ListMapp key={index} temp={temp} index={index} handler={some_fn}/>`
(`handler` is the prop you'll send to child and `sone_fn` will be the function that will receive data from the child)

In the child component, you can call props.handler(data) and send whatever data you want to send it to the parent.

Comment: Yup, tried this out, got the state back successfully. Thanks